# How to pass object to hashHistory.push() in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Anyone know how to pass an object to hashHistory.push()?

Here's a code snippet:

```
redirectToDrug(id, drug) {
  hashHistory.push(`/infusions/library/${id}`, drug);
}
```

Trying to get the drug information in there so that I dont have to query the database again for the drug info, as I already have it in the parent class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass object with query to push function:

```
router.push({
  pathname: `/infusions/library/${id}`,
  query: { drug }
})
```

And then to access your object in **/infusuons/library/${id}** page:

```
this.props.location.query.drug
```

[Link to official docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc)

It is good solution if your object isn't too complex, but if **drug** is a big structure of data, I'd use unidirectional data flow framework, for example [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: Cool, this definitely works, but is there another way to do so that doesnt create a query string thats added to the url? EDIT: nvm just did it with state instead of query

Answer (score 1):

You can pass json string of object as:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(drug);
hashHistory.push({pathname: `/infusions/library/${id}`, query: {data}});
```

If you pass direct object then you are unable to retrieve in another component. Above solution worked for me.